# UTF8 vs ASCII or custom binary format: high-performance optimization on very big tables

Tags: mysql, nosql, mariadb, utf-8

The summary of my question is whether there are advantages, even if minimal, to use ASCII, or even a smaller format designed yet created specifically for the situation, instead of UTF-8 for strings.

Is possible to use webserver who will access the data translate one ASCII string to a more compact format.

On this question, just 1-3 tables on database handle a massive amount of data, so any byte can make difference if could fit on memory instead of access disk. The information will be accessed via a RESTfull service

Read vs Writes:

Project need much more read than writes. But writing has a peculiarity: every 10 seconds an amount between 40-300 new rows are inserted into the main table. These could be written in parallel, since do not depend of each other.

Memory vs Disk usage:

Recent inserted rows, that will be used immediately, will be inserted also on a cache for the webservice use, so no need to read they again. But for search on old records, the database will need, and it should be fast.

This is why I suppose that use less bytes to store some fields will make diference: even for larger amount of data, will be more easy for fit on memory.

If I cannot fit data on memory, and database cannot abstract to me some speed, or I will need to force slow table/partition scans each 10 seconds for just one user, or I will be forced to do single select and cache it on Webserver, but this break concept of "stateless" from REST concept.

Characters that must be supported

0-9,A-Z, "-", "_". Maybe will need "a-z". Just 38 or 64 caracters, and never more than this.

For now, most columns are

```
CHAR(3), CHAR(6), VARCHAR(8), VARCHAR(10).
```

Examples:

- ABC, XYZ
- AB-EFG, XY-XPT
- ABC123457
- E47F6C, 34210A, E48D37 (hex strings, maybe exist a format specific to this?)

Technologies used

Database will be **MariaDB**. Maybe part of RAW data will be on some **NoSQL** database. The language of webservice does not really makes diference here, but will be PHP 5.4 with framework Phalcon PHP.

Different types of cache could be used, from Varnish-cache to APC/Mencached until caches inside database.

**My initial hypothesis**:

One field with `VARCHAR(10)` needs 80bits. If I use one custom table to use just 64 or less instead 255 characters, I save around 4 times, so instead of 80bits will use just 20bits.

Comment: When compared to `utf8mb4`, `ascii` column has the advantage that there is no way to accidentally insert non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your list of characters that must  be supported clearly indicates you need nothing more than plain `ascii`.

If you want to stored this as text, then this `ascii` is your most compact way. But here are a few clarifications:

- VARCHAR(10) does not "need" 80 bits. It *may* need 80 bits, if all characters are used, under `ascii` character set. If you only store 3 characters (e.g. `'abc'`), then it only needs 24 bits.
- `utf8` does not store more space than `ascii` when ascii characters are used. `'abc'` on both `utf8` and `ascii` encoding are 3 bytes long. That's why it's called utf-**8**: it attempts to only use 8 bits when possible.
- However on temporary tables (vanilla MySQL; solved on Percona Server; I'm not sure about MariaDB) a `utf8` character will take **3** bytes no matter what; same for `MEMORY` tables. So best use `ascii` if it fits your needs.
- You could compress further. You can use the `COMPRESS()` function, for example, or encode via your own method (if you only need **64** different characters, this means you're using **6** bits. This means for every **3** bytes (24 bits) you use today, you could squeeze in another byte (using **2** buts from each of the 3 bytes). So you can certainly compress by 25%, and possibly more. But this leaves you with `BINARY`/`VARBINAY` types, which are not as easy to work with: you'll have to always compress/decompress, you will not be able to index the text (alphabetically, that is; you can certainly put indexes on the column).
- The rest of the tools you mentioned are imho irrelevant; by the time your data reaches varnishd, your texts are uncompressed. Possibly so for PHP as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Shlomi. This project will take a while to start up, so I can take to give a feedback solution used.